# List of HTML tags deprecated in HTML5?

Tags: html

This is a good list of deprecated tags in HTML5: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm.  Is there an official list from the W3C?

Also, is there a list that states why specific tags have been deprecated and what has replaced them?

Comment: SO isn't really the place for off-site resource recommendations. You should know this after 5 years and 10.2k rep, arguably...

Comment: Obviously I disagree...and I'm not alone, as you can see by the great answers below.

Comment: How then do you explain the matching, hard-coded question closure reason in the "Close Question" dialog?

Comment: @4thSpace: Those answers are not great, they're terrible. They're just a bunch of links to off-site content. That's explicitly disallowed.

Comment: Thanks for the down votes.  It wouldn't be SO if those weren't there.  It would be nice if we could get a few more just for good measure.

Comment: There is an official list of obsolete elements. It's right in the HTML5 spec itself. [section 11.2](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#obsolete). Rob's answer provides the best info on the reasons why, but only covers changes from HTML4. Some obsolete elements like listing, plaintext were already obsolete, while the hgroup element was invented and obsoleted during the course of creating HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the W3C: [HTML5 Differences from HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/)

[This is from WHATWG](http://html-differences.whatwg.org/) but it's the same thing.

[Specifically, the obsoleted elements are here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-elements)

[And here are the attributes.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#obsolete-attributes)

However, there's a difference between "deprecated" and "obsolete". [Elements are no longer marked as "deprecated".](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#backward-compatibility)

> Since HTML has separate conformance requirements for Web developers
>   and user agents there is no longer a need for marking features
>   "deprecated".

Comment: Links are broken.

Comment: @vinS Thanks. Updated. These are now all pointing to the W3C site.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some lists that include the attributes and tags deprecated. Also, as the second link states (and although you specifically mention tags), many of the attributes and tags are deprecated because `...their functions are better handled by CSS.` - in other words, it was more appropriate for a CSS command to create the functionality than an HTML tag or attribute.

[Deprecated HTML Elements](http://www.html-5.com/changes/deprecated/)

[HTML5 Deprecated Tags](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_deprecated_tags.htm)

Comment: Both great answers.  It was difficult to mark one as THE answer but I chose the other only because it had a little more info, which is probably not the best way.  Big thanks!